# I want to run in android mobile my code for PDF viewing from url in to flex mobile application using ActionScript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5, flex-mobile

```
protected function printBtn_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
var webView:StageWebView = new StageWebView();
    webView = new StageWebView();  
                webView.loadURL("https://www.bobcards.com/images/pdf/Annexure_d.pdf");  
                webView.viewPort = new Rectangle(0, 0,this.stage.stageWidth, this.stage.stageHeight); 
                webView.stage = this.stage; 
}
```

This is my code it runs well on desktop but not running on android mobile. Kindly sugggest me how to do.
Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 0):

It's a shame but one still can't open an Adobe product (PDF) within another Adobe product (AIR) on Android. This is only possible by using an ANE (AIR Native Extension) that would open a file with the default application associated with a file extension on your mobile - with other words, your users will need to have the Adobe Reader or other PDF reader app installed on their device.

For example, this ANE would do it:
http://www.myflashlabs.com/product/pdf-reader-ane-adobe-air-native-extension/